# Transparently split file | Hardlink to file part

Tags: linux, file-management, truecrypt, hardlink

I have really big file (TrueCrypt container) and I want to save it in some cloud, but it has constraint on file size, limiting to 2 Gb, also it has some tool to sync directory. The idea is to create hardlinks to file parts in some directory, which would be synced.

For example: we have file *A* with size of 4 Kb; file *B* points to first 1Kb part of *A*, file *C* points to second 1Kb part of *A*, file *D* points to third 1Kb part of *A*, file *E* points to last 1Kb part of *A*.

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. What are possible alternatives?
3. If it is not possible at all, then I need TrueCrypt analogue that allows splitted containers and implements **all** features of TrueCrypt.

Constraints:

- OS: Gentoo Linux
- Total size increasing is **not allowed**
- Removal of original file is **not allowed**
- FS: Ext4 | ReiserFS

Comment: You forgot to mention what could storage do you use.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I didn't forget, I've deliberately ommited this information, cause almost no one knows it (But you do: cloud.mail.ru)

Comment: @smt did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can transparently access to different parts of file via loops. Below is a script what implements your example setup:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=A count=8
losetup --offset 0    --sizelimit 1024 /dev/loop0 A
losetup --offset 1024 --sizelimit 1024 /dev/loop1 A
losetup --offset 2048 --sizelimit 1024 /dev/loop2 A
losetup --offset 3072 --sizelimit 1024 /dev/loop3 A
```

As a result, parts of the initial file `A` are accessible via `/dev/loopX` files: whatever you write in `A` can be read from `/dev/loopX` and vice versa. I'm not sure your cloud client will work with special files though.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I think I'll run out of loop devices with 20Gb file, or I'm wrong? (`ls -l /dev | grep -P "loop[0-9]+" | wc -l` results to `8`)

Comment: If you have loop driver as a loadable module, edit `/etc/modules.conf` and add the following line: `options loop max_loop=20` and reboot. Otherwise you'll have to rebuild your kernel to support more loop devices.

Comment: Ok, then there are some more stupid questions: what is the maximum count of loop devices and how they affect on RAM and CPU? (source idea was to use 10Mb file parts with 20Gb container, now I don't know what size to choose)

Comment: loop device simply translates all incoming read/write calls on `/dev/loopX` to read/write calls on underlying file, so it doesn't take much RAM. Creating 2000 loop structures + 2000 file handles + 2000 block devices will consume maybe tens of MB at most. But why do you need so many?

Comment: You could also go the other way round, use several regular files, mount them as loop devices and then combine these loop devices using btrfs or lvm (similar to my answer). Then your cloud service would only have to deal with regular files.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be a better solution actually.

Answer (score 0):

Something that works with ZFS for sure, probably also with `lvm`, `btrfs` and other volume managers:

You could use several empty files (created with `dd if=/dev/zero of=file01 bs=1M count=2000`) and then use these files as "hard disks" in your volume manager to form a RAID0 (striping).

For `btrfs` and `lvm`, you have to mount your files as loop devices (see other answers).

Then the volume manager will present you these files as one big hard disk. You could place your truecrypt container inside this new filesystem.

[image]

For using LVM, a tutorial here: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/410/A_simple_introduction_to_working_with_LVM

For btrfs, it would probably be a command like
`mkfs.btrfs -d raid0 file1 file2 file3`
see: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Filesystem_creation

Since you are using Gentoo, you have to option to use ZFSonLinux (the kernel module, do NOT use the FUSE implementation!).
It could be done as follows:

```
# create 10 files of 1GB each
for i in {0..9} ; do
    dd bs=1M count=1000 if=/dev/zero of=part_${i}
done

# create a zpool (sth like a virtual harddrive) from the 10 files
zpool create MyPoolName /absolute/path/to/part_*

# this will also create a new file system, that is mounted at /MyPoolName
# can be seen with
df -h

# Now, you can put your Truecrypt container in there. If you want to upload/download the files, you should "export" the zpool first.
zpool export MyPoolName

# If all the synchronization is done, you can import the pool with
zpool import MyPoolName -d /absolute/path/to/folder/that/contains/parts
```

I recommend not to use too many small files, since there will be a big overhead involved. It is best to experiment a bit how to use ZFS and how well everything works with the cloud upload.

Comment: I've never used lvm, so how it can be done? (`man lvm` didn't help)

Comment: I also never used `lvm`. I use ZFSonLinux instead (which works really well) and updated the answer to give some more ideas. Also, check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS

Comment: OK, it looks like `lvm` only works if you mount your files using loop devices. Same goes for `btrfs`. So if you don't want to use ZFS, combine this answer with the answer of @DimitryGrigoryev .

Comment: The reason to use many small files is that cloud can't partialy sync files (as I know [yep, it's not really good cloud but gave me 1Tb, that I want to use :) ]), and it's at least strange to upload 2Gb after any change in container.

Comment: So how to combine ZFS with loop devices to achive >512Mb parts?

Comment: For ZFS, you don't even need loop devices. It can work with regular files as well. But if your cloud does not support partial sync, it is not good to use ZFS. You would have to upload EVERYTHING after a change (ZFS will spread the file over the available 2GB files).

Comment: Ok, I'll try your solution with hope on cloud provider...